# Как подключиться к удаленному компьютеру с помощью socket?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь связаться с удаленным компьютером с помощью модуля socket, то есть есть клиент/сервер.
У меня вопрос: если в сервере указано, например

```
portsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
portsock.bind((myHost, myPort))
```

то в клиенте я должен коннектиться соответственно с теми же myHost, myPort?

```
sock.connect((myHost, myPort))
```

На тестах по локалке все работает. Попытался подключиться удаленно - не работает. Время ожидания истекло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как подключиться к удаленному компьютеру с помощью socket?

1. Знать его имя (hostname). Или если имя сервера неизвестно, то можно использовать [`nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`](https://superuser.com/a/722397/13868), чтобы найти его внешний адрес
2. Убедиться, что исходящие/входящие соединения к данной машине, порту разрешены (настройки межсетевых экранов локальных/удалённых).

Например, чтобы подключиться к `time.nist.gov` серверу по порту `37`, можно использовать [`socket.create_connection()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/socket.py#l478):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import struct
from contextlib import closing
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def rfc868time2utc(ts, epoch=datetime(1900, 1, 1)):
    """http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc868"""
    return epoch + timedelta(seconds=ts)

address = "time.nist.gov", 37 # rfc 868
with closing(socket.create_connection(address, timeout=5)) as sock:
    buf = sock.recv(4)
    while len(buf) < 4:
        buf += sock.recv(3)
    ts, = struct.unpack('!I', buf[:4])
    print(rfc868time2utc(ts).isoformat() + 'Z')
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "Знать его имя (hostname)". Это просто скрипт на Python, который я запустил на удаленном компьютере, а с другого пытаюсь к нему достучаться. Нет у него никакого хоста.
Или вы имете в виду 
 
>>> socket.gethostname()
>>> zavulon-System-Product-Name

И использовать zavulon-System-Product-Name в качестве адреса сервера?

Comment: @Xyanight: *"Нет у него никакого хоста"* -- "удалённый компьютер/сервер/хост" разные имена в данном случае для машины, на которой сервер (приложение) запущен. Примеры имён: hashcode.ru, time.nist.gov, ya.ru. Если [доменное имя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F)  неизвестно, то можно по публичному ip обращаться (запустить приведённую выше nslookup/dig команду на сервере, чтобы узнать ip).

Comment: Давайте сначала... IP компьютера, на котором запущен скрипт сервера, я знаю - "192.168.2.100"

Кусок Server.py  
  
  sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
  sockobj.bind((, 7500))                                      
  sockobj.listen(5)
  
Кусок Client.py  

   sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 
   sockobj.connect(("192.168.2.100", 7500))

Comment: @Xyanight К Питону это уже слабое отношение имеет. Приведённая выше команда nslookup *не может* вернуть "192.x.x.x". Если Вы не знаете, что такое [частный ip адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81), NAT, файервол и т.д., то задайте отдельный вопрос, включив как можно больше о сетевой топологии между клиентом и сервером (находятся ли они в одной локальной сети? Планируется ли доступ к сервису через интернет?)

Comment: Возвращает IP команда socket.gethostname(), а не nslookup. Вышеприведенные примеры сервер-клиент работают на локальных компах. Сейчас потребовалось выполнить эти программы на удаленных друг от друга машинах. И здесь у меня возник подобный вопрос. Если это делается иначе, чем в локальных сетях, дайте ссыль на инфу. Спасибо!

Comment: @Xyanight: 1. я не вижу в моём ответе `socket.gethostname()` (не нужно эту функцию использовать). Я вижу только `nslookup` в моём ответе (можно ещё по ссылочке пройти и увидеть `dig` команду). 2. Да, это имеет значение, находятся ли клиент/сервер в одной локальной сети или нет. Короткой ссылки, описывающей, что такое интернет, как он устроен и описывающей все возможные варианты почему клиент до сервера не может достучаться -- я не знаю.